# Prove a given set on the euclidean plane is connected

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R},\ g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be functions, that satisfy $f(x)\leq g(x)\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:f(x)\leq y\leq g(x)\}$. Prove that if $f$ is continuous, then $S$ is connected on the euclidean plane.

$S$ set looks a bit like an open ball in continuous functions space with supremum metric. But I still don't see why is it important for $f$ to be continuous -- to my mind, if we were to make a discontinuity in one point, it wouldn't change the fact $S$ is connected. Isn't it connected by its' definition?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
A path from $(x', y')$ to $(x,y)$ within $S$ is
$$(x', y') \to (x', f(x')) \to (x, f(x)) \to (x, y)$$
Where the middle path is along $f$ and continuous because $f$ is continuous and the "side" paths are just straight lines trivially continuous and within $S$.